# Select all rows that contains malformed windows-1251 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, character-encoding

There are some entries in my database that contain malformed text.

For example text in KOI8-R encoding accidentally was put into a windows-1251 encoded table. So instead of the text `Шла Саша по шоссе`, I have `ыМБ уБЫБ РП ЫПУУЕ` in the database.

Is there a way I can select all `ыМБ уБЫБ РП ЫПУУЕ`-like entries?

I need to preform this both for MS SQL Server 2005 and 2014.

Comment: Not sure how to address this issue. Can you add a script to reprocude this situation?

Comment: @Horaciux script was written on self-made C-like language about 15 years ago, which is now a big problem. So code will explain you nothing due to proprietary nature. Let's say there is a function `GuessCoding` which sometimes guesses encoding wrong.